# Define reachableFrom graph using extendedRecursionEngine

Tags: haskell

I am trying to define reachableFrom using extendedRecursionEngine. It is useful to carry along a list of nodes that have already been expanded along a path. The value being passed along during the recursion is a pair (node_to_be_expanded, nodes_already_expanded).

This is what I could map out so far. I don't know how to implement it so I could run it without errors.

```
reachableFrom graph startNode = 
   extendedRecursionEngine
      (\ (node, expanded) ->         -- Stop if we have already expanded this node.
      (\ (node, _) -> Node node [])  -- If we are done, construct a Tree Node with no descendents.
      Node                           -- Build a Tree Node from a graph node and the returned subtrees.
      (\ (node, _) -> node)          -- Save the graph node for the reduceFn.
      (\ (node, expanded) ->         -- Construct a list of nodes that can be reached in one step.
                                     -- Also add the current node to expanded.
      (startNode, [])                -- Start at the start node. expanded is initially empty.
```

when we run reachable from it should give output like

```
> reachableFrom exampleGraph 2
Node 2 [ Node 3 [ Node 5 [ Node 2 []                     -- Don't expand 2 again.
                         , Node 6 []
                         ]
       , Node 4 [ Node 1 [ Node 2 []]]                   -- Don't expand 2 again.
       ]

> reachableFrom exampleGraph 4 
Node 4 [ Node 1 [ Node 2 [ Node 3 [ Node 5 [ Node 2 []   -- Don't expand 2 again.
                                           , Node 6 []
                                           ]
                         , Node 4 []                     -- Don't expand 4 again.
                         ]
                ]
       ]

> reachableFrom exampleGraph 5 
Node 5 [ Node 2 [ Node 3 [ Node 5 []]                    -- Don't expand 5 again.
                , Node 4 [ Node 1 [ Node 2 []]]          -- Don't expand 2 again.
                ]
       , Node 6 []
       ]
```

where exampleGraph and tree are defined as

```
-- Nodes are not declared explicitly. A value of type a is a node.
-- The nodes are linked by Links: (node_a, node_b)
data Tree a = Leaf | Node a [Tree a]
type Link a = (a, a)
data (Eq a, Show a) => 
     Graph a = Graph {nodes :: [a], links :: [Link a]} 
     deriving (Show, Eq)
-- A Graph is a collection of values (of type a) with Links joining them.

exampleGraph = 
  let node1 =  1      
      node2 =  2       
      node3 =  3       
      node4 =  4       
      node5 =  5       
      node6 =  6       
  in Graph [node1, node2, node3, node4, node5, node6] 
           [ (node1, node2)
           , (node2, node3)
           , (node2, node4)
           , (node3, node5)
           , (node5, node2)
           , (node4, node1)
           , (node5, node6)
           ]
```

This is what happens when I run this program.

```
> exampleGraph 
Graph {nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,6], links = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5),(5,2),(4,1),(5,6)]}
```

When I was trying to define reachableFrom, I came across this utility function that returns the nodes that a given node links to directly.

```
linksFrom :: (Eq a, Show a) => Graph a -> a -> [a]
linksFrom graph node = [n2 | (n1, n2) <- links graph, n1 == node]
```

I am not sure if I could use it in any way to define my reachableFrom.  How can I implement reachableFrom using this recursionEngine?

Comment: Tagged as Homework.  The only thing I find when I Google for "extendedRecursionEngine" is this question and CSU course CS 332F

Comment: @Paul: We [don't need the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812) to ask the OP to [improve](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) their question by showing what they've tried, stating unique restrictions, or asking about the specific part that is confusing them (rather than post the problem statement and ask for general help).

Answer (score 1):

Ok After playing with it for a while, I got the answer. 
Here how we define reachableFrom function.

```
reachableFrom graph startNode = 
   extendedRecursionEngine
      (\ (node, expanded) -> node `elem` expanded )       -- Stop if we have already expanded node.
      (\ (node, _) -> Node node [])  -- If we are done, construct a Tree Node with no descendents.
      Node                           -- Build a Tree Node from a graph node and the returned subtrees.
      (\ (node, _) -> node)          -- Save the graph node for the reduceFn.
      (\(node, expanded) -> [ (myNode, node:expanded) | myNode <- linksFrom graph node ])       -- Construct a list of nodes that can be reached in one step. myNode
                                     -- Also add the current node to expanded.
      (startNode, [])               -- Start at the start node. expanded is initially empty.
```